# How to link javaDocs between an api class and its implementation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, comments, javadoc

I am busy struggling to get java Docs to show on the implementation side of a class.
I have an api class in which all the docs reside at and on the implementation side nothing shows up. I have seen it working through Eclipse but our company standards are IntelliJ.
I can't find information on linking docs from api to implementaion so I was hoping I could get some help on how to achieve this goal

Example
API class

```
public interface Builder {
/**
 * Adds an interaction to the agents latest interaction.
 * It is stored inside the cahce
 * If the interaction already exists in the list it is moved from its position to the top
 * If the interaction does not exist in the list the eldest interaction is removed and the
 * new interaction is added to the top
 * @param interaction
 * @param amountOfAgentPreviouseInteraction
 */
public void updateInteraction(Interaction interaction, int amountOfAgentPreviouseInteraction);
}
```

[image]

and this is the java doc on my implementation side

[image]

and the implementation does implement that api class

```
@Named
public class BuilderImpl implements Builder {
public void updateInteraction(Interaction interaction, int amountOfAgentPreviouseInteraction){
//Some logic here
}

}
```

Also I did try `@link` and `@see`.

It seems like a farely simple task but I can't find a solution.

Thank you for your time

EDIT: Ok so I forgot to mention that the api and implementation is not in the same project.

Comment: It will happen automatically if you generate all the Javadoc at the same time. Otherwise you would need to use the Javadoc `-link` option to link the implementation classes back to the interface classes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `{@inheritDoc}` inside the documentation comment of your method implementation.

Comment: I tried the `{@inheritDoc}` but no luck. I saw that my language level on my projects was 5 so I bumped it to 8. I also failed to mention that the api class in a complete different project then the implementation